# How can I get the second higher number in a query

Tags: mysql

Example, Lets suppose I have a table like next one:

```
id | start | userId
1      3       1
2      2       2
3      5       1
```

Now, I want to get all the row information for the second higher value of the column `start` related to some `userId`. So, if `userId` equals to `1` I'm expecting to get the next result:

```
(id, start, userId) = (1,3,1)
```

I have tried this query:

```
SELECT id, max(start) FROM table_user WHERE userId = 1;
```

But this gives me the higher number.

Comment: Your query isn't even valid SQL..

Comment: I use it without problem

Comment: Yes because MySQL extends `GROUP BY` feature try it running with `SET SESSION sql_mode = (SELECT CONCAT(@@sql_mode,',ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'));`  and see what [happens](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/huxTjM7pHzhDfboZoYfmx3/1)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easy using ordering by column `start` and the features of `LIMIT`, like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table_user
WHERE
    userId = 1
ORDER BY
    `start` DESC LIMIT 1, 1
```

You can check this online also: [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3g83mERwLnCz5kvJwksyKR/2)

Comment: But I need to filter by userId